# JavaScript Taking in values from text box store into an array create new array to sort

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, function, dom

Hey guys i have some code here that dynamically creates text boxes when a button is clicked however, i would like to take in the text box values by using getElementByClassName, Retrieve all of the "listitem" text fields into an array.Then I code a loop to find the values of each of those elements (ex. what the user entered) and put those values in an array. Then sort that array. I will then display them later on...
Any help is appericated!

Javascript:

```
var $ = function (id)
{
  return document.getElementById(id);
}

var sortItem = function ()
{
  var myDisplayItems = "";
  myDisplayItems.innerHTML = "";

  var myClassTag = document.getElementsByClassName("listitem");
  for (index in myClassTag)
  {
    myDisplayItems += "<br>" + myClassTag[index];
  }
  //sort Array

 }
 var addItem = function()
 {
 var myToDoList = $("todolist");

  var myInput = document.createElement("input");
  myInput.setAttribute("type", "text");
  myInput.setAttribute("class", "listitem");
  myToDoList.appendChild(myInput);

  var myBr = document.createElement("br");
  myDoToList.appendChild(myBr);
 } 

 window.onload = function ()
 {
   $("additem").onclick = addItem;
   $("sortitems").onclick = sortItem;   
 }
```

HTML:

```
  <body>
  <h1>ToDo List - Date: <span id='today'>&nbsp;</span></h1>

  <div id="todolist">
  <p>
    <input type="button" id="additem" value="Add Item">
  </p>
  </div>

  <hr>

  <div>
<p>
    <input type="button" id="sortitems" value="Sort and Display Items">
</p>

<p id="displayitems">
</p>
  </div>
 </body>
```

Comment: It seems like you described the answer in the question. Use `getElementsByClassName`, then loop through the values. If you have an implementation that doesn't work, you should post that code, and we could help.

Comment: When i click the button to sort the array i get an error saying that the "myDisplayItems.sort()" is not a function that is why i commented out the line.

Comment: That's because myDisplayItems is not an array, it's a string. You can learn about arrays here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

Comment: You are right forgot to declare as myDisplayItems = new array();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit modified original code

HTML

```
<h1>ToDo List - Date: <span id='today'>&nbsp;</span></h1>
    <div id="todolist">
        <p><input type="button" id="additem" value="Add Item" /></p>
    </div>
<hr>

<div>
    <p><input type="button" id="sortitems" value="Sort and Display Items" /></p>
    <p id="displayitems"></p>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
var sortItem = function(){
    var myClassTag = document.getElementsByClassName("listitem");
    //convert nodelist ot array
    myClassTag     = Array.prototype.slice.call(myClassTag, 0);
    //let the sort function sort it for you
    myClassTag.sort(function(a, b){
        return a.value > b.value ? 1 : -1;
    });

    var myToDoList = document.getElementById('todolist');
    //update items position
    update(myToDoList, myClassTag);
}
//update items position, reappending will do the job
function update(target, listOfItems){
    for(var i = 0; i < listOfItems.length; i++){
        target.appendChild(listOfItems[i]);
    }
}

var addItem = function(){
     var myToDoList = document.getElementById('todolist');
     var myInput    = document.createElement("input");

     myInput.setAttribute("type", "text");
     myInput.setAttribute("class", "listitem");
     myToDoList.appendChild(myInput);

     var myBr = document.createElement("br");
     myToDoList.appendChild(myBr);
}

window.onload = function(){
     document.getElementById('additem').addEventListener('click', addItem);
     document.getElementById('sortitems').addEventListener('click', sortItem);
}
```

**UPD**
You can modify update function, to make it works as you wanted, ex:

```
for(var i = 0; i < listOfItems.length; i++){
    var child = document.createElement('span');
    child.innerText = listOfItems[i].value;
    target.appendChild(child);
}
```

Comment: This works, but i don't need the text boxes to be re-arranged. I will display the sorted array beneath the sort and display button using the DOM methods and properties after the array gets sorted. thanks anyways. @Dart